# Get data from mysql according to column PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql table "booking" and i want to get result according to PaymentStatus

Table booking

```
id      shop_id      paymentStatus      amount      
1       2            1                  50      
2       2            1                  60
3       2            2                  40
4       2            2                  90
```

I want to get Total number of booking according to PaymentStatus (result should like 2 booking for paymentStatus=1 , 2 for paymentStatus=2)
and Total amount according to PaymentStatus (Total amount 110 for PaymentStatus=1 , Total amount 130 for paymentStatus=2) 
How can i do this ?

Comment: hi, welcome to stackoverflow. what you have tried? have you checked w3school's guide on [sql tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT paymentStatus, COUNT(id) total_bookings, SUM(amount) total_amount FROM `bookings` GROUP BY paymentStatus
```

Comment: This answer is missing its explanation.  Stackoverflow is not a pile of snippets, it is an educational resource for researchers.